# dynamic list in .text section

Tags: c

honestly i don't known how to post this question...
I have a global dynamic list that is visible by all function of the program,
since today this list were filled reading data from a file.
but now i want to have a internal "list" that is loaded if no file it's specified.
the list element are this:

```
// odb tuple
typedef struct _odb_t
{
const char *name,*value;
struct _odb_t *next;
} odb_t;

enum _method {GET,POST};

// odb type binding
typedef struct _odb_type
{
    enum _type type;
    const char *value;
    struct _odb_type *next;
} odb_type;

// defining online_db struct
typedef struct _odb
{
    const char *host,*file,*patrn;
    enum _method method;
    odb_type *types;
    odb_t *tuples;
    pthread_t thread; // the thread that is using this host
    struct _odb *next;
} odb;
```

how can i have an internal list into the .text section?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C99 you can have so-called compound literals as some kind of unnamed variables and designated initializers to ease the writing of initializers. Your structures are a bit complicate that I can capture their complete meaning on a first glance, but something analogous to that here should work.

```
odb const*const head = 
 &(odb const){
  .method = something,
  .next   = &(odb const){
     .method = another,
     .next = 0,
  },
};
```

Sure that you would have to initialize the other pointer fields analogously with the correct data, but I hope you get the idea.

When used in file scope compound literals of the form `(typename){ initiliazers }` are allocated statically.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply.
2 things:
1) the `const*const` is an error right?!
2) why `const` is after `odb` ?
thanks again!

Comment: This is a unmutable pointer to an unmutable object. If you need both `const` or not is up to you. Your question was not sufficiently precise to know if you want that list to be modifiable or not.

Comment: Ah, and `const` after the type is one possibility. I always find it easier to read since if you write it that way the `const` is always applicable to what is written on its left.

Comment: thanks i solved with &(odb){ "host","file","patrn",&(odb_type){type,NULL,NULL},&(odb_t){"name","value",NULL},0,&(odb){others structs...}};
thanks again :)